# Proper Alignment and Distribution selection for Horizontal StackView

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

Following is the screenshot showing the design I want to implement.

[image]

For this, I am using a vertical stackview that encompasses four other horizontal stackviews. Then each horizontal stackview includes an image and a label as indicated below.

[image]

I set the `alignment` of the horizontal stackviews `fill` and tried changing the `Distribution`. However, I am not able to get the desired result.

What `alignment`/`distribution` combination could generate the desired effect?
Or should I eliminate horizontal stackviews and populate views inside the vertical stackview?

Comment: Can you please post the result you are obtaining? You could also try a vertical stackview for all the icons and a vertical stackview for all the labels, both inside an horizontal stackview.

Comment: What do you get now? Post a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a tableView , but if you have a few items then

[image]

setting a spacing for the main stackview and every inner stackView should give the needed padding

[image]
[image]

for Full look check the demo

https://github.com/ShKhan9/stackV

Comment: The solution works but one thing that I wonder is that if we are setting the image width and height, then does not this prevent image scaling (1x, 2x, 3x images) for differently sized devices?

Comment: no,it'll not prevent it and it's up to you to increase that width/height

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps,

**1.** Add a `vertical stackView` with `top, leading and trailing constraints` to the `view`.

```
Alignment - Fill
Distribution - Fill
Spacing - 20
```

**2.** Add 1 `horizontal stackView` to the `vertical stackView`

```
Alignment - Fill
Distribution - Fill
Spacing - 20
```

**3.** Add `imageView` with `height and width constraints set to 30` in the above `horizontal stackView`.

**4.** Duplicate the `horizontal stackView` in `vertical stackView` the number of times as per your requirement.

[image]

Comment: Can this be done without defining image height and width (Step 3) [Please refer to my comment under Sh_Khan's answer]? And Step 4 does not seem to be required.

Comment: If you have the image of small size you won't need that. Setting imageView's contentMode to scaleAspectFit will work. And ya Sept-4 won't be needed. Added that by mistake.